# How to retain data in Azure Log Analytics beyond the 31 days?

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I am looking into options for retaining data beyond the 31 days that Azure Log Analytics supports.  I tried reading the documentation, but I haven’t been able to figure it out yet.  How should this be architected?  Is the expectation that the logs should be archived to a cold Azure Storage account outside of this using some other method from the data source, or is there a way to route the parsed log data from Azure Analytics Logs to an Azure Storage account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using a free tier, you could change Log Analytics `data retention` settings up to 730 days. Read more details [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/canberrapfe/2017/01/25/change-oms-log-analytics-retention-period-in-the-azure-portal/).
[image]

Generally, you could do the following things with diagnostic logs.

> - Save them to a Storage Account for auditing or manual inspection. You
>     can specify the retention time (in days) using resource diagnostic
>     settings.
> - Stream them to Event Hubs for ingestion by a third-party
>     service or custom analytics solution such as Power BI.
> - Analyze them with Azure Monitor, where the data is written immediately to Azure
>     Monitor with no need to first write the data to storage.

Depend on your usage, you could select to store these logs in a storage account. Here is a [sample Powershell script](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-samples/blob/master/storage/post-storage-logs-to-log-analytics/PostStorageLogs2LogAnalytics.ps1) to show how to convert Storage Analytics log data to JSON format and post the JSON data to a Log Analytics workspace.

References: [Query Azure Storage analytics logs in Azure Log Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/query-azure-storage-analytics-logs-in-azure-log-analytics/)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is that data flow Virtual Machine > Analytics Logs > Storage Account, or should the logs be routed to both the Analytics Logs and Storage Account independently?

Comment: Yes, that is the data flow. It is two methods to store the logs, you could select one.

Comment: I prefer the VM > Analytics > Storage Account path, but I can’t figure out any obvious way to accomplish this.  Do you know if this is part of the standard Azure platform, or do I have to do this using Automation/Runbooks?

Comment: I mean the path: vm->Monitoring->diagnostic settings->pick a storage account in the portal UI. For the query logs, you can try to export it in the UI.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other obvious way to export the log query directly to the storage account. Maybe you could try to convert Storage Analytics log data to JSON format and post the JSON data to a Log Analytics workspace in my reply.

Comment: Please feel free to let me know if you still have any question in your case or accept this answer if this's helpful.

Comment: do we need to put retention policy in diagnostics settings using terraform, or retention is globally managed at Log Analytics workspace level?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer summarized log should be stored outside of Log Analytics. Can we cascade the query result to backup to other cold storage like DataLake, DataBricks, ADX ? So VM > Monitoring > KQLQuery > Storage path is more flexible. And it might realize consistent summary between  monitoring (using KQL & dashboard) in log analytics and long term analytics (using DataLake etc...) outside.

And of course support of automation by Azure Data Factory or LogicApps are highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, @omdit, your response sound more like additional questions than answer to my original question :) I would suggest starting a new post if asking more questions.  Aside from this, I do agree that going from Log Analytics to cold storage would ideal.